# How to add to a parent event handler in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a React page setup root container page with a global Header component and some child components (via React Router, but that might not be relevant). The Header component has buttons that need to do specific things (like navigate) but also need to have functionality dictated by the child components. I have looked around for information on callbacks and props, but I am at a loss on how to achieve this. (Note, I am also using Redux but my understanding is that you should not save functions in Redux state because they are not serializable).

A simplified version of my scenario:

```
// Container Page
const Container = () => {
  const onNavigate = () => {
    // How could Cat or Dog component add extra functionality here before navigate() is called?
    navigate('/complete');
  };

  return (
    <Header onButtonClick={onNavigate}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/cats' component={Cat} />
      <Route path='/dogs' component={Dog} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

// Cat component 
const Cat = (props) => {

  const speakBeforeNavigating = () => {
    // This needs to happen when the "Navigate" button in the Header is clicked
    console.log("Meow!");
  };

  return (
    <span>It is a cat</span>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your requirements.  `onNavigate` always navigates to the `'/complete'` page, but we want to extend the behavior depending on the page that we are currently on.  Is that correct?  The real question is -- are these callback functions pure functions that we can call from `Container` just by knowing if it's Cat or Dog, or does the callback need to access the internal state of the `Cat` component?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying questions. I may have oversimplified a little: The navigation is also dynamic based on the page but I've managed to solve that using Redux state. The callbacks may also use Redux state but otherwise we can consider them pure functions (no internal state from the Cat/Dog component).

Comment: (The other detail missing is that there may be many more components than just Cat/Dog. The point was to de-couple the header from those components to allow any number of new types to be added there. But, the hope is with this framework they will al work the same way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is that you define all of the callbacks in the parent component, which is why I had to double check with you that the callbacks don't need to access the internal state of the child components.

I would define the props for each `Route` individually, and include a `callback` along with the props.

```
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: "/cats",
    component: Cat,
    callback: () => console.log("Meow!")
  },
  {
    path: "/dogs",
    component: Dog,
    callback: () => console.log("Woof!")
  }
];

// Container Page
const Container = () => {
  // functionality is based on the current page
  const match = useRouteMatch();

  // need history in order to navigate
  const history = useHistory();

  const onNavigate = () => {
    // find the config for the current page
    const currentRoute = ROUTES.find((route) => route.path === match.path);
    // do the callback
    currentRoute?.callback();
    // navigate
    history.push("/complete");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header onButtonClick={onNavigate} />
      <Switch>
        {ROUTES.map((props) => (
          <Route key={props.path} {...props} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I had actually started down this path but was adding the ROUTES to redux store when I learned you shouldn't add functions there. Now I realize I can have it elsewhere and just save the key/index/path to the correct route in redux to get to the correct callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use context api and send it as prop. While sending it as a prop you can pass callback function to your onNavigate function. Like this

```
const onNavigate = (callback) => {
  callback();

  navigate('/complete');
}
```

And you use it like this

```
<button onClick={() => onNavigate(() => console.log('blabla'))}
```

For context api information I recommend you to check React official documentation.